# XML to Object to Database

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to store xml values into two different tables of a database.

Right now I'm using LINQ, but I can't get it to work as I want.

This is the XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <nfeProc xmlns="http://www.tst.com">
    <NFe xmlns="http://www.tst.com">
      <infNFe Id="409" versao="2.00">
        <ide>
          <cUF>43</cUF> 
          <cNF>00011740</cNF> 
        </ide>
        <emit>
          <GGT>0483</GGT> 
        </emit> 
        <det nItem="1">
          <prod>
            <cProd>27</cProd> 
            <NCM>85437099</NCM> 
          </prod>
        </det>
        <det nItem="2">
          <prod>
            <cProd>30</cProd> 
            <NCM>85457099</NCM> 
         </prod>
        </det> 
      </infNFe>
    </NFe>
  </nfeProc>
```

Right now I'm using the following code:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@file);
XNamespace a = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe";

     var NFe = from data in xml.Descendants(a + "nfeProc")
               select new
                  {
                    cUF = (string)data.Elements(a + "NFe").Elements(a + "infNFe").Elements(a + "ide").Elements(a + "cUF").FirstOrDefault(),
                    nNF = (string)data.Elements(a + "NFe").Elements(a + "infNFe").Elements(a + "ide").Elements(a + "nNF").FirstOrDefault(),  
                   };

      var Prod = from Produto in xml.Descendants(a + "det")
                 select new
                    {                                           
                      cProd = (string)Produto.Elements(a + "prod").Elements(a + "cProd").FirstOrDefault(),
                      NCM = (string)Produto.Elements(a + "prod").Elements(a + "NCM").FirstOrDefault(),
                     };

     foreach (var nf in NFe)
       {
       }
     foreach (var p in prod)
       {
       }
```

Then I use ADO.NET to send to the database. But I would like to do in only one foreach, so I could use the `OUTPUT` clause from SQL Server to relate the two collections(get ID from table 1(NFe) and INSERT into table 2(Prod)). How can I achieve that. I tried a lot of things with no success. I tried in one:

```
var NFe from data in xml.Descendants(a + "nfeProc")
               select new {}...
```

But this way I only can get one "cProd" and not all of them.

Other approaches are welcome.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers, but actually I got it to work simply changing my foreach.

```
   foreach (var nf in NFe)
   {
       foreach (var p in prod)
       { 

       }
   }
```

This way I can use cmd.ExecuteScalar() to get OUTPUT.ID from my first foreach and use it in the next INSERT in my second foreach.

Comment: There is only ever going to be one "nfeProc" as that is the root node.  No need to do a `Descendants` on it. It is the same as your `xml.Root` node.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to word your `var Prod` is

```
var Prod = xml.Descendants(a + "cProd")
              .Select(x => new
              {
                 cProd = (string)x,
                 NCM = (string)x.Parent.Element(a + "NCM")
              });
```

Or if you absolutely know the NCM node follows the cProd node

```
NCM = (string)(XElement)x.NextNode
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been around since .Net 1.1 I guess and no longer in fashion, yet you can:

1. Create a schema out of your xml file. Without any manual intervention (no element reorganizations, type or namespace customizations) this looks like:
   [image: XML->Create Schema]
2. [Generate a strongly typed dataset out of your xsd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or you can use the /c switch for xsd instead of /d and generate classes instead of a typed dataset. Either way you got yourself *a data access layer for free*. You can [read xml into a dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with one of the `DataSet.ReadXml` overloads and use that to persist to database or data binding.